# как увеличить картинку больше оригинала

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc, fancybox

есть сайт https://editpress.ru/Home/Item/?id=1fcd1a9e-fb36-47ca-803c-018b41293aaa
на нем подключен fancybox. Оригинальные картинки малы сами по себе. Как их увеличить в popup окне?

Comment: На сайт ходить не будем. 1. У `<img width= height=` есть теги задающие размер. Достаточно задать один из них больше размера - и размер увеличится.

Comment: я пробовал так - #main-image {
    width:200%;
    height:200%;
} не помогло. И вообще--если я задам теги как у Вас -будет ли это кроссбраузерно и кросс девайсово?

Comment: CSS не управляет атрибутами. Если вы уж так хотите через CSS, то переключите позицирование `{position:relative; .... }` тогда width и height будут иметь силу.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding    : 0,
        margin     : 5,
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'none',
        autoCenter : false,
        afterLoad  : function () {
            $.extend(this, {
                aspectRatio : false,
                type    : 'html',
                width   : '100%',
                height  : '100%',
                content : '<div class="fancybox-image" style="background-image:url(' + this.href + '); background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100%;width:100%;" /></div>'
            });
        }
    });
```

вот это немного помогло, но теперь картинка обрезается в модальном окне [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]